# Need help in this array destructuring and intialize value in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce, destructuring

```
let Arr = ["a","b","'c','d'","e","f"]
```

need to store value in object like with fixed key name

```
obj = {hey: "a", hello: "b", how: "'c','d'",are: "e",you:"f"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Arr.reduce((a,c,i)=> (a[keys[i]]=c,a),{});
```

```js
let Arr = ["a","b","'c','d'","e","f"];
let keys = ["hey","hello","how","are","you"];

let obj = Arr.reduce((a,c,i)=> (a[keys[i]]=c,a),{});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I have updated the question, kindly share response.

Comment: @RaghavSehgal I also update answer

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce function and inside the accumulator object create a new key with by cancating `temp` and index

```js
let arr = ["a", "b", "'c','d'", "e"];

let newObj = arr.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  acc['temp' + index] = curr;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let Arr = ["a","b","'c','d'","e"].reduce((acc, val, index) => {
  acc[`temp${index}`] = val;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```js
let Arr = ["a", "b", "'c','d'", "e"];

let Obj = {};

Arr.forEach((s, i) => { Obj['temp' + (i || '')] = s; });

console.log(Obj);
```